# Finding the domain of absolute convergence in complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the domain of absolute convergence for:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (\frac{z-i} {z+2i})^n $$

I have attempted to solving this using the root test:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{T_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(\frac{z-i} {z+2i})^n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{z-i} {z+2i}| $

$ |\frac{z-i} {z+2i}| < 1 $

$ |z-i| < |z+2i| $

$ |z-i|^2 < |z+2i|^2 $

$ (z-i)(\overline {z-i}) < (z+2i)(\overline {z+2i})  $

$ (z-i)(\overline {z} +i) < (z+2i)(\overline {z} -2i)  $

$ |z|^2 + i(z-\overline {z}) +1 < |z|^2 + 2i (\overline {z} -z) + 4  $

$ i(z-\overline {z}) < 2i (\overline {z} -z) + 3 $

Comment: Did you take the n-th root on the *original expression* ? I think you should use its complex absolute value...

Comment: Why did you conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{z - i}{z + 2i} = 1$? This is wrong for the vast majority of $z$.

Comment: Yes I believe that's how the root test works. It works by taking the nth root of the original expression, then finding the limit for it.

Comment: @T.Bongers Opps! That is right. I thought the limit is on z not n. I am correcting it now. Thank you.

Comment: Next issue: The root test is about the absolute value of $T_n$, not just $T_n$.

Comment: I corrected it, but in this case z is a complex variable, I understand it as a pair of values, how do we find the absolute value for it other than calculating r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2).

Comment: @T.Bongers does this look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum |w|^n < \infty$ iff $|w|<1,$ your series converges absolutely iff $|z-i|/|z+2i|<1,$ which is the same as saying $|z-i| < |z+2i|.$ We can rewrite that as $|z-i| < |z- (-2i)|.$ So we are looking for the set of points $z$ in the plane whose distance to $i$ is less than its distance to $-2i.$

Now if I gave you the geometry problem of describing the set of points in the $x,y$ plane closer to $(0,1)$ than to $(0,-2),$ you'd be able to do it: First draw the perpendicular bisector between these points, which is the line $y = -1/2.$ Then the set we're after is the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $y>-1/2.$ In other words, the domain of absolute convergence for your series is the set of $z=x+iy$ such that $y>-1/2.$

Answer (score 1):

The condition is simply that $\vert\frac{z-i}{z+2i}\vert<1$ (then it's a geometric sum). Tak this expression squared and try to solve the inequation $\vert z-i\vert^2<\vert z+2i\vert^2$ which is equivalent to $-3<i(z-\bar z)$.

Now write $z=a+ib$ and the solution should appear.

EDIT : Just to be clear, the solution you wanted to used, often called the Cauchy criterion was not a bad idea, and you would have obtained the same result using it. It's just that using such a powerful technique on a geometric sum feels like using a hammer to smash a flee (I don't know if this expression exists in english).

Comment: How did we go from inequation $\vert z-i\vert^2<\vert z+2i\vert^2$ to $-1<i(z-\bar z)$.

Comment: Write $\vert z-i \vert=(z-i)(\overline {z -i})=(z-i)(\bar z +i)=\vert z\vert^2 + i(z-\bar z)+1$ and do the same for $\vert z +2i\vert$ and then rearrange the terms.

Comment: I did that, but did not get the same answer. I updated the question with my attempt. Could you please tell me what am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: My bad there was a mistake in my answer I just updated it. You did your calculations right. Now expressing $i(z-\bar z)$ as $2\mathfrak {Im}(z)$ should give you the condition you want.

Comment: I also added a remark with respect to your first attempt